# Writing a Show instance for Data.Functor.Compose without FlexibleContexts

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm experimenting with [`Data.Functor.Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Compose.html) and wanted to write a Show instance for it when trying things out in ghci. What I have (which is working) is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
instance (Show (f (g a))) => Show (Compose f g a) where
    show = show . getCompose
```

What I was wondering is: is there a way to write this Show instance without FlexibleContexts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think it is possible. To quote the [GHC documentation for FlexibleContexts](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-rules):

> In Haskell 98, the assertions in the context of the instance declaration must be of the form C a where a is a type variable that occurs in the head.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any documentation that you know of that would describe these sorts of "non-representable" cases in the language?

Comment: Besides the Haskell report and the GHC documentation, nothing comes to my mind.